# Eclipse RCP - feature only present in about dialog after product export, not when executed in IDE

Tags: eclipse-rcp, about-box

I am working on the about-dialog of my Eclipse RCP Applicaiton.

The features, which I am using (native platform features and my own) only show up, when I do an export from Eclipse.

When I run my product in the IDE - the about dialog stays empty. The feature icons do not show up.

**Question:** Where is the problem?

**About dialog, when the product was exported:**

[image]

**About dialog, when the product is started inside of the IDE:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although unexpected, I think that's normal.  I see the same behavior in my RCP application.

Comment: I found out, that when including the Feature "org.eclipse.rcp" into my dependencies - makes it apear, when the application is started from the IDE, so it is possible somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Window>Preferences`. Under `Plug-In Development>Target Platform`, set up your target platform to match the product you are exporting. You can use org.eclipse.rcp as a base and go from there, adding features from either Eclipse itself, or from a p2 repo.

The default is to load the IDE itself as part of the runtime configuration.

That said, I am not sure the Features dialog actually works when running from within the IDE. I remember from a while back that there was a limitation here, but unfortunately I can no longer find a reference to this.

Comment: What do you mean by "set up your target platform to match the product". Do you want me to use the product as a target?

Comment: adding my feature's folder to the target does not work. The feature's path is not resolved correctly.